# UISearchDisplayController Not Displaying Results in searchResultsTableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, search, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UISearchDisplayController` properly connected to the header of a custom `UITableView` in IB. However, when I search for anything the `searchResultsTableView` only displays "No Results", and I cannot seem to find where the code is incorrect.

**`searchResults` Property**

```
- (NSMutableArray *)searchResults {
    if (!_searchResults) {
        _searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.listingPreviews.count];
    }

    return _searchResults;
}
```

**Table View Data Source Methods**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSInteger numberOfRows = 0;

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        numberOfRows = self.listingPreviews.count;
    } else {
        numberOfRows = self.searchResults.count;
    }

    return numberOfRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Listing";
    ListingPreviewTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ListingPreviewTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        cell.listingPreview = [self.listingPreviews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        NSLog([[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title]);
        cell.listingPreview = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**Search Bar Delegate Method**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSInteger searchTextLength = searchText.length;

    for (ListingPreview *listingPreview in self.listingPreviews) {
        if ((listingPreview.title.length >= searchTextLength) && ([listingPreview.title rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound)) {
            [self.searchResults addObject:listingPreview];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just try this instead:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Listing";
ListingPreviewTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell.
if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    cell.listingPreview = [self.listingPreviews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    NSLog([[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title]);
    cell.listingPreview = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
```

}

Please note that the change was applied on:

ListingPreviewTableViewCell *cell = [**self.tableView** dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

This way you deque a Cell from your own tableView and not from the one created by UISearchDisplayController.

Comment: god bless you. I was banging my head on a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that nothing in your code forces searchDisplayController to reload it's searchResultTableView.

The standard approach is to set `UISearcDisplayController's` delegate (note the protocol - `UISearchDisplayDelegate`) and implement `– searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:`

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {

    // perform your search here and update self.searchResults
    NSInteger searchStringLength = searchString.length;

    for (ListingPreview *listingPreview in self.listingPreviews) {
        if ((listingPreview.title.length >= searchStringLength) && ([listingPreview.title rangeOfString:searchString].location != NSNotFound)) {
            [self.searchResults addObject:listingPreview];
        }
    }

    // returning YES will force searchResultController to reload search results table view
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The documentation says that `shouldReloadTableForSearchString:` is an optional method and that "if you don’t implement this method, then the results table is reloaded as soon as the search string changes", which is definitely the desired behavior. I have the `UISearchDisplayController`'s delegate set appropriately.

Comment: Despite this, I still tried what you said by commenting out `searchBar:textDidChange:` and replacing it with `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString`, using the exact same code. The `searchResultsTableView` does not display "No Results", but it just displays a bunch of blank cells.

Comment: @sethfri have you set `searchResultsDataSource` and `searchResultsDelegate` for your `UISearchDisplayController` than?

Comment: Yes. I dragged the `UISearchDisplayController` into the header of the `UITableView` in IB, which sets all of the connections automatically. I have also confirmed that the connections are as they should be.